# if B is n square matrix anad invertible then $\text{rank}(AB)=\text{rank}(A)$

Tags: matrices

If $B$ is $n$-square matrix and invertible ,
how can we show that
  $\text{rank}(AB)=\text{rank}(A)$ for every $m\times n$ matrix $A$?

Comment: What do you know about rank, and what do you know about invertible matrices? Presumably, stitching together a proof from what you know about these things isn't too hard.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It's a useful reference, but that's a [tag:proof-verification] post. There are many other ways to prove this. At least, that's my 2 cents.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, but at least there is a proof, and that's what the question wants, and also, what you have suggested.